# Different Screen Size bootstrap Navbar center alignment

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

Can anyone help me center my Bootstrap Navbar when I change screen size?

And also I'm using a normal div, for the footer I need to center align it too.

[image]

```
<style type="text/css">
    .navbar-nav > li{
      padding-right:3px;
    }
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                    <li class="active"><a href="index.php" style="margin-left:91px;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> LINK</a></li>

                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dorpdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">LINK<b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="dorpdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" >LINK<b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
                        </ul>               </ul>

            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*One way can be :*

**Bootply** : http://www.bootply.com/QCmMLYr56f

**CSS**:

```
ul.navbar-nav{
    width: 100%;
    text-align:center
}

.navbar-nav li{
   display: inline-block;
    float: none;
    background:cyan;
  }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="index.php" style="margin-left:91px;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> LINK</a></li>

                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dorpdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">LINK<b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="dorpdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">LINK<b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
                        </ul>               </li></ul>

            </div>
```

Comment: This one works, but when i open the dropdown link it the bottom-border line gets in half of the li tag.
http://i.imgur.com/kqIdjb9.jpg

Comment: I can't do something with a screenshot... Can you share the url ? Or reproduced the problem in a fiddle/bootply ?

Comment: Sorry but this isnt working for me, other links on the dropdown menu arent aragned as they should. With this one it gets worse  :(

Comment: And i want them to be like these one,but navbar to be center aligned in all screen sizes:
http://www.bootply.com/yQVKTWHroq

Comment: Ok : Add ".navbar-nav li li{
   display: block;
  }"    bootply : http://www.bootply.com/WN9CksWa5J

Comment: Why doesn't it work ? the navbar is in yellow, and the items in cyan in the fiddle :http://www.bootply.com/t67hF1N9o3

Comment: that one helped me bootply.com/WN9CksWa5J 
Thanks for your help.
I have one more question i have a normal div. and i want to center align it can someone solve it ?

Comment: Post your question as a new question please, it's not the same topic : but :  <div style="text-align:center">your div</div>

Comment: Ok i will post a new question.

Comment: Guys im having trouble, i need to make the mobile view links also 
.navbar-nav li li{ display: block; }
Anyone has idea how to, cuz it displays them inline.
Tryed this code but wont do the job.

`@media (max-width: 768px) { 
  .navbar-nav li li{ display: block; }
}`

Answer (score 1):

I Think you could try this div around your navbar:

```
#global {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: ...;
}
```

Juste change the `width` with your own value :)

Comment: Did you put the div around your nav_bar ?

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap uses class container to center elements. You could try something like:

```
<div class="container"> <!-- Start Container -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse"> <!-- Start Navbar-->
         <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
             <li class="active"><a href="index.php" style="margin-left:91px;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> LINK</a></li>    
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dorpdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">LINK<b class="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <a href="#" class="dorpdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" >LINK<b class="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
                          </ul>        
       </ul>

    </div> <!--End Navbar-->
</div> <!-- End Container -->
```

Comment: Look this fiddle with your code :http://www.bootply.com/gFiYr9nZLr, The content is not align in center, it's just aligned to the left border of the .container

Comment: @TheLittlePig this doenst works, because i want a full width navbar, and this one does not.